# Continuous poling with javascript - will this way work

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I want to be able to set up continuous poling so that updates are detected as soon as they are available.

I have this javascript function.

```
        function getMessage() {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", "@routes.Application.receive()");
                request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE &&
                            request.status === 200) {
                                displayMessage(request.responseText);
                                getMessage()
                        }
                };
```

1. Will this system work or will it generate some kind of stack overflow error eventually because for every message it performs a recursive call.  Any suggestions to improve this?  Is there a better idiomatic way to do it?
2. How can I set a time out?   What is the default time out?  And How can I detect when a time out has occurred?

Thanks a lot

PS I made this function based on what I have read on SO.  There was a function that seemed to handle things like time outs but it was using JQuery.  I am not familiar with it and was wondering if the same could be done in pure JS.

Comment: `1.` Why not just try it and see `2.` [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Comment: No, there won't be a stackoverflow unless you're using a synchronous request.

Comment: why use short polling when so many better options are available?

Answer (score 0):

This should be OK, but better replace `getMessage()` with `setTimeout(getMessage, 500)` to avoid flooding the server.